# How to get parent element's ID?

Tags: javascript

So I got into this tricky situation. I have a variable which present table data:

```
row += '<td>' + c + '<button class="btn btn-success" id="' + callId + ' " onclick="handleCall()">Call</button>'  + '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="' + hangupId + ' " onclick="handleHangUp()">Hangup</button>' + '</td>' ;
```

Latter on I will append that into my table. Now, when I click Call button, I want to get the button's Id. I have tried this way:

```
function handleClick() {
console.log(this);
}
```

but it refer to window object. Can anybody show me the way to achieve my goal? Thanks

Comment: `onclick="handleCall(this)"`, `function handleClick(element)`

Comment: BTW, this is surely a duplicate. But I guess it's simpler to answer than look for a dupe!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply pass the elements ID as a parameter to keep it simple,

Change,

```
onclick="handleCall()"
```

to,

```
onclick="handleCall(this.id)"
```

`this` referring to the button in question the user is pressing.

then,

```
function handleClick(id) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

Finally don't use inline event handlers as they are a pain to work with in the long run, make use of the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
row += '<td>' + c + '<button class="btn btn-success" id="' + callId + ' " onclick="handleCall(this)">Call</button>'  + '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="' + hangupId + ' " onclick="handleHangUp()">Hangup</button>' + '</td>' ;

function handleClick(element) {
console.log(element);
//here you will have all element properties
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways you can do this, you can do it via `jQuery` by using `attr` or if you are wanting to stay vanilla `Javascript` then you can use `.id`.

For `jQuery`  please see code below:

```
console.log(jQuery('element').attr('id'));
```

For `Javascript` please see code below:

```
console.log(element.id);
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with jQuery, and that is very bad code regardless.  The answer to the query you suggest will *always* be "test"

Comment: Updated my answer with Javascript option. Whats wrong with the jQuery code i provided then?

Comment: It basically says "get the id of the element with this id".  It's just not relevant to the question.  The vanilla javascript answer is also wrong and irrelevant to the question.  It will retrieve a nodeList and try to get the id of that.  It's just completely unhelpful to the questioner.

Comment: It also basically says "get id of the element with this class", "get the id of the element with this element type", "get the id of the element with this attribute" Its not just restricted to getting elements by ID is it? 

Instead of telling people that their answer is wrong, how about you try to provide a useful answer yourself and maybe educate others around you instead of trying to be a self proclaimed Javascript "guru".

Comment: Calm down.  I'm telling you what's wrong in order to help you as well as the OP.  This is Stack Overflow - not 4chan.  `jQuery("element")` will find nothing - "element" is neither a class or an id, so unless you've used an incorrect tag in the markup then it will find nothing.

Comment: Okay let me rephrase my point, you can use `jQuery("input[type=text]")` which is neither a class or id, yet it will still return the node list.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but that's not what your answer says.  The answer, as it currently stands, is incorrect and no help to the questioner.  Your answer looks like you're trying to get the id of an element, but that's not what the question is.  Look at the accepted answer and see if that makes it clearer.